# Groovy set .each behavior for my class

Tags: class, groovy, each

I have a class in my project with a List defined in it. Would it be possible to point `each` (and all subsequent related methods such as `eachWithIndex`) to use that List.

The only possible solution I can see would be to make my class extend `List`, which I would rather not do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`@Delegate`](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html) transformation as below which delegates those method calls to `List` :

```
class Test {
    @Delegate List myList
}

new Test(myList: [1, 2, 3]).each { println it }

new Test(myList: ['a', 'b', 'c']).eachWithIndex { val, index -> 
    println "$val at $index" 
}
```

Comment: This is great, I knew Groovy would have something for that!

Comment: Also keep an eye on the technical notes in the API.